# equals() and hashCode()

Tags: java, hashcode

Как написать `equals()` and `hashCode()` для класса у которого есть только одно контейнерное поле, например:

```
class Clazz{
     private List<...> list = new ArrayList<>(); 
}
```

**Обновление**

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {

    if (this == obj){

        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass()){
        return false;
    }

    AnotherClazz clazz2 = (AnotherClazz) obj;

    if (Objects.equals(this.toString(), word.toString())){
        return true;
    }
        return !(clazz1!= null ? !list.equals(clazz2.list) : clazz2.list != null);
}
```

Вот так?

Comment: ну `equals` видимо тупо сравнить контейнеры. хеш-код тут уже от того что внутри списка зависит.

Comment: для `List` в спецификации [определены](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) `equals` и `hashCode`, поэтому точно так же, как для любого другого поля ссылочного типа.

Comment: ах да точно!!!!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Т.к. это просто контейнер, имеет смысл просто сравнивать непосредственно скрытый объект и возвращать результат его `.hashcode()`. equals/hashcode говорят о том, являются ли объекты равными, а различаться контейнерам больше и нечем, поэтому задача тупо спускается на уровень ниже.

При условии работы в Java 7+ проще всего делегировать эти задачи на класс-утилиту `Objects`, чтобы не заморачиваться каждый раз с null.

```
class Container<T> {

    private T value;

    public boolean equals(Obj that) {
        if (that == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(that instanceof Container) {
            return false;
        }
        return Objects.equals(value, that.getValue());
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(value);
    }
}
```